# Visual Studio not able to save html file edit

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Weird issue, just tried to save a static html file that I had made a quick edit to, using Visual Studio 2015, and a message pops up that says "file already exists do you want to overwrite". I click "yes" button, and get another message that says "The process cannot access file "c:/nnnnn.html", the file is being used by another process".

What gives? Is this a bug?

Quick update: Only happens with .htm file extensions. The .html file extension works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only happens with .htm file extensions. The .html file extension works as expected.

A bit more detail: As it turns out, IIS Express process was still running in the system tray even though the Debugger had ended. I have found this to be common in this newer version of Visual Studio, IIS Express stays running, perhaps for faster starts when debugging. But I have had a few issues where I have had to go back and actually close it to complete some other task. Funny that it can be running and does not disrupt saving .html files but does disrupt saving .htm files.